# Image of Gauss Map of the Hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm asked to describe the image of the Gauss map for the hyperboloid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$. Considered the parametrization $\sigma(x,y)=(a\cosh (x)\cos (y),b\cosh(x)\sin(y),c\sinh(x))$.

My idea was to look at a domain in the $xy$ plane and see where those points land on the sphere.

$\nu_{\sigma}(x,y)=\nu\circ\sigma(x,y)$. Where $\nu_{\sigma}=\frac{\sigma_{x}\times \sigma_{y}}{||\sigma_{x}\times \sigma_{y}||}$

But I can't really see how to plot these points.

Comment: I suggest you think about the problem first when $a=b$ and you can use symmetry about the $z$-axis. Can you answer the question in this case? Now how does it change when $a\ne b$?